# JS Submit not the same as HTML Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that requires a Submit, now for design reasons I have had to relocate the code for the submit of these forms and use JS to actually submit them.

This has been workig fine, no problems until I hvae found a form that also does a further peice of JS that no longer fires...

My submit JS is as follows:

```
function submitform()
{
    document.details.submit();
}
```

This works great. However this is another piece of JS that does work when using the HTML Button:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('#sortdata').val($( "#sortable" ).sortable("serialize"));
    return true;
});
```

Any help/advice would be brilliant as am just going round in circles with changing the names of elements in the JS. This surely has to be possible no?

Comment: What is the difference are you finding? Check your Network tab to see what is getting posted!

Comment: Do you have jQuery referenced? That second example uses it

Comment: I do have JQuery involved in all of this, Is the JQuery Sortable? It doesnt get the ordering from the sortable list and so wipes all the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery submit method to trigger event handlers attached with jQuery:

```
$(document.details).submit(); //shorthand for .trigger('submit')
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ba9kq/)

This will submit the form in the same fashion, but also trigger the `submit` event handlers bound to that element with jQuery before doing so.

---

The issue was that the native [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) method is not warranted to trigger event handlers bound with jQuery (or any event handler at all):

> The form's `onsubmit` event handler (for example, `onsubmit="return false;"`) will not be triggered when invoking this method from Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.

In other hand, jQuery's `.submit()`/`.trigger('submit')` will always¹ execute the event handlers attached through jQuery to that element.

- [jQuery `.trigger()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

---

¹ Except if `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` was called previously for the given event but that's a completely different topic.