# HTMLFormElement submit and reset methods relation with event handlers

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

The [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) DOM interface provides the `.submit()` and `.reset()` methods, which I'm heavily making use of in my single-page app.

Right now I'm trying to figure out the relation between these two methods and triggering the `form` element's `onsubmit` and `onreset` event handler methods.

---

### Test case

So considering this perfectly valid HTML5 document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>HTMLFormElement method-event relation test page</title>
<form style="border:solid">
  <input name=foo>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button type=reset>Reset</button>
</form>
<button id=js-submit>.submit()</button>
<button id=js-reset>.reset()</button>
```

And the following JS `<script>` content right below the form:

```js
(function() {
    var qs = function(s) {
            return document.querySelector(s);
        },
        form = qs('form');
    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
        console.log('onsubmit fired');
        return false;
    };
    form.onreset = function(e) {
        console.log('onreset fired');
        return false;
    };
    qs('#js-submit').onclick = function() {
        form.submit();
    };
    qs('#js-reset').onclick = function() {
        form.reset();
    };
}());
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SX5EX/3/show/)

* Side-note: I know `addEventListener` may be preferred over `onevent` handlers, however it'd have the same effect and this is merely a simple, IE8-compatible illustration.

Clicking the Submit and Reset buttons inside the `form` fire the corresponding `onsubmit` and `onreset` methods just fine, as these are user actions the event handlers must be triggered.

The buttons outside of the form call the `form` element's `.submit()` and `.reset()` methods, that is, the methods which I'm programmatically calling in my real code.

Normally, as I'm programmatically calling simple `form` methods from code-side, I'd expect these to not trigger any form event.

**However**, clicking the `.reset()` button **does** dispatch an `onreset` event to the `form`, while `.submit()` **does not** dispatch any event to the `form`. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE8.

* The behavior is the same when using `addEventListener` instead of `on*` handlers.

---

### Question

Is there a standard expected behavior for whether event handlers will be triggered when a `form`'s `.submit()` and `.reset()` methods are called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.submit()` method is not warranted to (and most often does not) trigger the `onsubmit` event due to historical reasons. It is worth noting that modern browsers (latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and even IE8) **do not** trigger the `onsubmit` event when calling `form.submit()`.

The `.reset()` method in the other hand, follows the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357) and performs the same action as clicking a reset button, which includes dispatching the `onreset` event to the form. Tested in the same browsers as the paragraph above.

---

### Reference

[`HTMLFormElement.submit` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit):

> The form's `onsubmit` event handler (for example, `onsubmit="return
>   false;"`) will not be triggered when invoking this method from
>   Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be
>   invoked by HTML user agents.

[DOM Level 2 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357):

> #### Methods
>
> **reset**
>   Restores a form element's default values. It performs the same action as a reset button.
>
> **submit**
>   Submits the form. It performs the same action as a submit button.
>
> [...]
>
> Note: The onsubmit even handler is not guaranteed to be triggered when invoking this method. The behavior is inconsistent for historical reasons and authors should not rely on a particular one.

[W3C mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2012JanMar/0011.html):

> > **submit**
> >     Submits the form. It performs the same action as a submit button.
>
> I don't think the last sentence is correct. Using a submit input will
>   trigger onsubmit. The submit method will not. [...]

Comment: Just wanted to share a night of headaches' result, and justifying to my OCD-self why `.submit()` does not trigger `onsubmit` while `.reset()` triggers `onreset`.

Comment: I feel your pain. Unlike vanilla-js, jQuery does trigger submit handlers if you trigger submit (but I expected it not to).

Comment: @bfavaretto Thank you. I'm using jQuery in this project, but what really got me intrigued was a vanilla `form.reset()` (inside my ajax submit success callback) that did trigger the given form's `onreset` event when I didn't expect it to. It also reminded me that in numerous cases I've used the vanilla `form.submit()` which does not trigger handlers (e.g. this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17235881) I've answered, and I also use it from the console to bypass JS validation when testing server-side validation), so I wanted to find a clear spec of how/why these work this way. `=]`

Comment: Yeah, that's the pain I was talking about, the OCD thing... :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer remains valid in 2022.
I just wanted to add a note, that there are still inconsistencies between browsers today.
For example if you *dispatch a custom event* named **reset** on a form element, *chrome will ignore it*, but **firefox will actually reset** the form as if you called form.reset() or clicked a reset button.